# Работа с БД Access [c#]

Tags: c#, access, sql, база-данных

**Каким образом можно сохранить данные из dataSet?**

```
Update(dataSet); - ошибка.
```

> *Динамическое создание SQL для UpdateCommand не поддерживается для
> SelectCommand, не возвращающей никаких
> сведений о столбце ключей.*

Comment: написано же - в результатах выборки нужны ключи. у вас они есть?

Comment: а каким образом можно сделать поле ключевым?

Comment: выполнить в той же базе alter table add constraint. точный синтаксис смотрите в справке акцесса. ну или через сам акцесс можно изменить таблицу.

Comment: "через сам акцесс можно изменить таблицу". 
Работа с таблицей производится в программе, в том числе и её создание.

Comment: тогда читайте справку по jet-диалекту SQL. и да - при создании таблицы ключевые поля можно задать сразу же.

Comment: Почитаю про это. Но пока что воспользовался запросом, который Вы предложили. И теперь ошибка следующего вида: 

**Динамическое создание SQL не поддерживается для SelectCommand, не возвращающего никакой информации о базовой таблице.**